# How to order by included model property in LoopBack JS

Tags: javascript, node.js, loopbackjs

I have a person model which has a belongsTo relations with a meeting model. I´m doing the query

```
Person.find({include:['meetings']})
```

Which gives me a result like this one:

```
    person:{
        name:"person 1",
        age: 15
        meeting:{
            name: "The meeting",
            date:"June 26, 2019 11:13:00"
        }
    }
```

What I would like to do is to order the results of the find function by the meeting date. Is there any way I can achieve this on a single query?

I´ve tried this:

```
Person.find({include:['meeting'],order:"meeting.date DESC"})
```

But server crashed when trying this. Can anyone help me achieve this?

Answer (score 1):

Ordering can be done through model.json file as below:

```
{
    ...
    "scope": {
        "order": "properyName <ASC/DESC>"
    },
    ...
}
```

By default, ordering is in ascending order so no need to add ASC explicitly.

Answer (score 0):

Try this :

```
Person.find({
  include:{
    relation: 'meetings',
    scope: {
      order: 'date DESC'
    }
  }
});
```

Comment: Note that this will sort the Meetings inside each Person, not the Persons.